# How to establish the communication between spring and opencms?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, content-management-system, opencms

I already developed a spring application with xml configuration and as a view technology I used JSP's.Now I got a requirement to integrate my application with opencms(content management system) . My application contains a blog page when user clicked on blog I want to replace body content of that jsp with the page designed in opencms and I want to change the body content frequently through OpenCMS.I referred lot of articles such as [Referred link-1](https://shinesolutions.com/2013/04/09/integrating-springmvc-with-opencms/)

[Referred link-2](https://www.bbsmax.com/A/gAJGeLlndZ/) [Referred Documentation link](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Spring)

I'm using spring 4 with hibernate 4 and opencms latest stable version.I failed to integrate with my application.Send me the sample application If anyone already integrated or give your suggestions & guidelines.

Comment: I really appreciated your post, I also searched a lot regarding this integration (CMS with Spring) in my previous project but unfortunately i haven't found any clear reference any solutions will be appreciated